# Can one read Tehillim or Tanach at night?

Tags: tanach, mysticism-kabbalah, tehilim-psalms, evening-night

I remember hearing people quote sources that say it is better not to reading Tehillim or Tanach at night.

Does anyone know the source to this, and to why it should not be read at night? Does one also know of any sources that do permit it to be read at night?

Please cite specific sources so I can see them inside.