# Saying Tehilim after shkia

Tags: zemanim, tehilim-psalms, evening-night

I understand [you can't say Tehilim at night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27923). Can you say Tehilim between shkiah and tzeits hakochavim (ben hashmashot)? or does it have to be said before shkiah?

Comment: Why would you think you can or can't? (answer by [edit]ing your question.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one read Tehillim or Tanach at night?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37794/can-one-read-tehillim-or-tanach-at-night)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason that you are not allowed to learn Torah shebictav at night?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/what-is-the-reason-that-you-are-not-allowed-to-learn-torah-shebictav-at-night)

Comment: This seems to not be a duplicate of either - it is accepting not to say at night (without being very clear about it) and asking when that begins.

Answer (score 2):

It is specifically from tzeis hakochavim, (see piskei teshuvos 238:3)

Comment: Who wrote piskei teshuvos?

Comment: @DovidBenizri If this answer worked for you, you can tell us that by clicking the green arrow next to the answer, to mark it as "accepted." FYI.